# Create docker service in manager node

Tags: docker, containers, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

Is there a way to force the creation of a docker service in a Docker Swarm in the manager node?

I can not use the `--constraint node.hostname=...` because I don't know the specific hostname for each stage where I deploy my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--constraint node.role==manager`